# Remap touch bar control keys, e.g., Siri

Tags: keybindings, touch-bar

I'd like to customize what the keys in my Macbook Pro's touch bar do. For instance, I have no interest in Siri but I'd be great to have the Siri key be the hotkey for iterm2 for instance.

Is there a way to customize the action for the "system" part of the touch bar's keys?

Answer (score 1):

Whilst you can't completely customise the actions provided in the control strip, you can replace or remove buttons with other Apple-provided buttons. Go to System Preferences → Keyboard → Customise Control Strip… and replace the buttons on the Touch Bar with any other options.